# Is it worth trying to reuse test fixtures as much as possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest

I have to work with Rails fixtures on an existing project. Switching to `FactoryGirl` or the like is not an option.

In my fixtures I normally have some generic once (records that would appear most often in the production database) plus a fair portion of fixtures for testing the edge cases. In a case of a blog app the latter could be a blog with no posts, a blog that haven't been active for a while, or a blog with no follower.

What is your take on creating a separate set of fixture records for every edge case versus trying to reuse existing fixtures as much as possible? The latter could include mocking / stubbing calls to specific methods (e.g. `Account.any_instance.expects(:post_limit).returns(1000)` with `Mocha`) or even creating records inconsistent with the application logic (say, having several users per account when your app only allows to have one user per account).

Answer (score 1):

I avoid creating data fixtures for uncommon use cases. But if I have a few scenarios that are checked in multiple parts of the app then I create them in fixtures because I consider it part of the test language of the app.

For edge cases I create the data in the test. Either by modifying a known fixture record, or by creating new records that meet the edge case criteria. You don't need tools like Factory Girl to create reusable factories. (Every ActiveRecord model is a factory.) You can create some well named methods in a module and then include it in your test class.

I would not mock your models like you outlined. I would create the records in the test and then test that the application behaves correctly.

```
def test_lots_of_posts
  account = new_account_with_n_posts 100
  assert(account.posts > 5)
end

def new_account_with_n_posts count
  account = Account.create! name: "Temp Account"
  count.times do |n|
    account.posts.create! title: "Temp Post #{n}"
  end
  account
end
```

Comment: That's a very valuable advice. Thanks!